# Excess space between span and border-bottom

Tags: html, css

Sometimes there is weird space between the span and border bottom. Particularly when viewing on mobile device. You can see the screenshot here:
[image: screenshot]

Code

```css
.heading {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fb7a6d;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 18px 0;
  clear: both;
}

.heading span {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fb7a6d;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 3px 16px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .heading {
    padding: 2px 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2 class="heading"><span>Price and release date</span></h2>
```

Comment: you have padding: 2px in your .heading. try to change it to : 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
    .heading {
        padding: 2px 25px 0 25px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .heading {
    padding: 2px 25px 0px 25px;
    //padding: 0px 25px 0px 25px;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `margin-top:-1px;` in `.heading span`.